# Connecting to CnosDB with FlightSQL in Grafana prompts: bad request data

Tags: cnosdb

Connecting to CnosDB with FlightSQL in Grafana prompts: bad request data

Reproduce the steps:

1. Start CnosDB and map port 8904.

```
docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --name cnosdb -p 8901-8905:8901-8905 -d cnosdb/cnosdb:community-latest cnosdb run -M singleton --config /etc/cnosdb/cnosdb.conf
```

2. Install FlightSQL data source in Grafana and restart the Grafana service.

```
grafana-cli plugins install influxdata-flightsql-datasource
```

3. Add the FlithtSQL data source and add connection configuration.
4. Click the Save&test button.